# How to access the value of a map field in cloud_firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am using cloud_firestore: ^0.8.2+2 - I am trying to access a **map field** on a document called "entity" with a key value pair. The key = "id" and the value = "1" .

I have tried using the following syntax `documents[index].data['entity.id']` - unsuccessfully.

I have successfully accessed a non map field title using the following syntax. `documents[index].data['title'].toString()`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Firebase Database Structure]

[image: Extract of Code]

Comment: Have you tried documents[index].data['entity']['id'] ?

Comment: You are kidding that was exactly it. I swear I tried that thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it was resolved `documents[index].data['entity']['id']`. Thank you @anmol.majhail